# build failing after adding jruby in ruby project

Tags: java, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby

I have setup my java package where I have written few java methods.
I want to call those methods from Ruby on Rails website but it's not working. I'm trying to do one POC for it but it's not working.

I installed jruby for it but build is failing. It's not able to find gems.

ruby gems environment:

gem env

RubyGems Environment:

- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.6
- RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2019-09-09 patchlevel 0) [java]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /local/home/skkundra/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.6.0
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/skkundra/.gem/jruby/2.5.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /local/home/skkundra/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/bin/jruby
- GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /local/home/skkundra/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.6.0/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/skkundra/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY:

/local/home/skkundra/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:

```
- ruby

- universal-java-1.8
```

- GEM PATHS:

  - /local/home/skkundra/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.6.0
  - /local/home/skkundra/.rvm/rubies/jruby-
    9.2.6.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared
- GEM CONFIGURATION:

  - :update_sources => true
  - :verbose => true
  - :backtrace => false
  - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
- REMOTE SOURCES:

  - https://rubygems.org/
- SHELL PATH:

  - /home/skkundra/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.6.0/bin
  - /home/skkundra/.rvm/gems/jruby-9.2.6.0@global/bin
  - /home/skkundra/.rvm/rubies/jruby-9.2.6.0/bin
  - /home/skkundra/.rvm/bin
  - /home/skkundra/.toolbox/bin
  - /usr/NX/bin
  - /usr/local/bin
  - /bin
  - /usr/bin
  - /home/skkundra/bin
  - /usr/local/sbin
  - /usr/sbin
  - /sbin

I'm getting

/home/skkundra/VPSInvoiceCentralWebsite/env/VPSInvoiceCentralWebsite-1.0/runtime/ruby2.3.x/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'thread_safe' (~> 0.1) - did find: [thread_safe-0.3.6-java] (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: Have you done `bundle install`?

Comment: I did bundle install..I got this error         "Could not find gem 'foc-common-assets java' in any of the gem sources listed in
your Gemfile."   Gem I created is "foc-common-assets" but it's adding platform at the gemname end. I tried "bundle lock --add-platform ruby". Then I got "Could not find gem 'foc-common-assets' in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile." Error.  So basically it's not able to find gems which were created before.

Comment: Where is foc-common-assets hosted, on rubygems? Does your Gemfile have a `source` line?

Comment: They are in other packages. It don't have source line of foc-common-assets. Actually foc-common-assets is the gem created in other package and I use many such gems in many other packages. So do I need to give the source of all the gems?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "package"?

Comment: Basically, in my rails website I have multiple packages which are rendering different page. So package you can treat as for different page there are gems located at different places.